# Encrypt string client-side so server can guarantee data is coming from client and hasn't been user generated

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, .net-core

We have a Xamarin.Forms (iOS and Android) application and an Angular8 webapp that both communicate with a .net core 2.2 webapi. We use JWT bearer token authentication to authorize our users to perform certain actions against our API.

What I need now is to be able to encrypt/obfuscate part of the data sent in our JSON requests client-side so, when the server receives the data, it can verify that the data originates from one of our apps and hasn't been manually generated and sent over PostMan (for example).

I have been looking into implementing public-key encryption, where we would store the publickey client-side in secure-storage and the private key would only be available server-side, but I'm not sure if this is the preferred method.

Just to be clear, we're not looking to implement full-message security at this point; we simply want to make sure that a user can't manually create a request on their machine and send the data to our API without using our client application.

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: There's no way to guarantee that a client cannot fake a request. If someone has your app, they have whatever keys and obfuscation methods you've built into that app. The only thing you can do is slow them down, and you have to balance how much time and cost you're willing to sink into doing that because it has very diminishing returns. At the end of the day, the server is the only source of truth and the place you should have your most thorough request validation.

Comment: @IanKemp Like you correctly mention, we're simply trying to slow-down and complicate 'spoofing' attacks as much as reasonably possible. Without getting into too much detail, the idea is that the client app gathers some real-time information and this information is then sent to the server which verifies that the client complies with a number of requirements before allowing it to perform certain actions. It's this information that we'd like to avoid users manually entering into a request body and sending over to the server without some kind of barriers...

Answer (score 0):

one of the main advantages of a Jwt is that you indeed *can* verify that the token was generated by the valid provider.

The token will contain a `keyid`, which gives you the public key of the provider[the server] and you can verify that.

There are libraries that will let you do this easily in Java - `com.auth0` : *jwt* and *rsa*.

a sample code may look like this,

```java
JwkProvider provider = new JwkProviderBuilder(new URL(<your-uri>)).build();

DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(jwt);
Jwk jwk = provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey();
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(pubKey, null);
Verification verifier = JWT.require(algorithm);
verifier.build().verify(decodedJWT);
```

Comment: My issue isn't with JWT verification. We already perform all checks on JWT bearer tokens server-side where they are generated. What I'm having issues with is validating the origin of the contents of the body of the message which contains the token. The client could easily capture his auth token from the app's network requests and then proceed to build his own version of the body data and simply include the JWT token to auth the request. And, as far as I understand, token generation should always be the sole responsibility of the server...

Comment: The point of token is it's signed so that we can verify the source. It's not possible for anyone else to "concoct" a payload , since it would fail the signature check. 

JWT includes 3 parts, one of them is *Payload*,

In *Payload*, you can add custom information. And **THIS** information is called *Claim*. In claim if you add any custom information, it cannot be tampered with since it's signed by the provider.

That's how you ensure the temper-proof nature of client-sent info.

if one attempts to "*build*", it will not have the right signature and will fail verification.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you're proposing that I should generate a JWT token client-side which would then be included in the Request body that's sent to the server? Now that I think about it, I never considered the option of generating JWT tokens client-side as I have always associated these with backend authentication/authorization... Thanks for the tip! I'll look into this, and if it, in fact, works as suggested I'll make sure to mark your answer as accepted!

Comment: Well, the JwT is generated by a legit OAUTH provider[a server]. you certainly don't want a "client" generating arbitrary content and have it *signed/validated* by a trusted authority. Hence, the content comes from attributes associated with the client account/credentials; it's **tied** to the client account residing in the OAUTH server[such as Azure AD, keycloak etc.] so it's legit and not tampered.